# Proxy HTTP with express.js and apache

Tags: node.js, apache, express, proxy, http-proxy

I want to securize php page from apache. This can only be accessed by NodeJS, because authentication is implemented from nodejs side. 
So i have to create a proxy HTT before accessing php page (that does not implement security).

Here is my virtualhosts apache :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:1882>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"

  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from localhost
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1882>
    ServerName ***
    ServerAlias ApplicationServer
    ProxyRequests Off

    ErrorLog "${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/app_error.log"
  CustomLog "${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/app_access.log" combined

    <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

So architecture is like :

Virtualhost2 apache (for HTTPS) -> nodejs application (for serving several thing and secure connection and session) -> virtualhost1 apache (for serving php file).

Here is the code of my proxy HTTP using nodejs :

```
// proxy.js
var router = require('express').Router();
const request = require('request');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // correct URL
    var proxy = request(req.url);
    req.pipe(proxy);
    proxy.pipe(res)
})

module.exports = function (auth_fn) {
    if (auth_fn !== undefined) router.use(auth_fn);
    return router;
}

//index.js

...
const auth = require("./auth.js")(app);
var proxy = require("./router/proxy.js")(auth.authenticate);
app.use("/locales", proxy)
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
})
...
```

I want to access to my PHP page from "/locales/"

From now, when accessing to localhost:3000/locales/index.php, nothing happen, and the proxy function is not triggered.

## EDIT :

Here is apache output, next to a proxy request :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2017:11:45:59 +0100] "-" 408 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2017:11:45:59 +0100] "-" 408 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2017:11:45:59 +0100] "-" 408 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2017:11:45:59 +0100] "-" 408 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Dec/2017:11:45:59 +0100] "-" 408 -
```

Note that everything work fine when i call page from localhost by using direct url